# UITableView, UISWitch and NSUserdefaults combination?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a `UITableView`. There are only two sections. In the first section there are only two rows. The first row only holds a switch. If this switch is turned On, the second row shows up.

Now I want to save the status of the switch. For that I use `NSUserDefaults` which code I've added to the action associated to the switch. The action of the switch (interruptor) looks like that:

```
-(IBAction)accioInterruptor:(id)sender{

NSUserDefaults *pepe=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pepe setBool:interruptor.isOn forKey:@"interruptor"];
[pepe synchronize];

NSLog(@"Defaults interruptor %d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"interruptor"]);
NSLog(@"Interruptor isOn: %d", interruptor.isOn);


    [infoAndSettingsTable beginUpdates];
    [infoAndSettingsTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [infoAndSettingsTable endUpdates];}
```

I seem to be, somehow, able save and restore the switch's state by adding  the state in the definition of the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, like this:

```
if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0){

    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.interruptor];
    [interruptor setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"interruptor"]];



    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"";
}
```

I added NSLogs at viewDidLoad and in the switch's actions, which look like this:

```
    NSLog(@" interruptor Defaults at startup %d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"interruptor"]);
    NSLog(@"interruptor isOn? %d", interruptor.isOn);
```

Now, the problem I'm having here is that when the switch is saved as "ON", the second row on the first section does not appear, it only shows the first row with the switch. If I turn the switch off and on again, then is OK. What I also don't understand is that the NSLogs at viewDidLoad, when the switch is saved as ON, show this:

```
 interruptor Defaults at startup: 1
 interruptor isOn:0
```

which I cannot understand how's that possible. Apparently, the saved state is ON, it's shown as ON (blue color) but when asked, the switch says it's OFF.

I though that would be a easy thing to do, but I've been having two hell of nights. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, never mind. I got it to work.

I previously tried to add

```
switch.on=[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switch"];
```

to the `viewDidLoad` but it didn't work.

As it turns out, I was missing a `self.` before the `switch.on`.

It now works like a charm.